# Here MAP using intent

Tags: here-api

Hi I would like to open the Here map installed on my android device from my application , using intent to display navigation from source to destination . Please suggest what value/parameter should be passed.

Answer (score 0):

The HERE application supports the standard google intents for location. Please see: [link](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common.html)

To directly link into the HERE application for directions and navigation, please contact our technical support team for the HERE Android intent document.

Comment: HI David  ,  i found the following url scheme which can be used  but non of them  provides the navigation from Source to destination.   geo:latitude,longitude, geo:latitude,longitude?z=zoom, geo:0,0?q=lat,lng(label), geo:0,0?q=my+street+address.  The Source address is not my current location.

Comment: Maybe you can try using the HERE Link Builder API http://heremaps.github.io/map-linkbuilder-app/